# Is this a drain, trap, or something else?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, sink

I removed a cabinet sink in my bathroom, and found this cover/hole underneath.  What is it?  Is it some old drain, a trap, or something else? I did not want to take the cover completely off until I knew what it was.  The screw appears to go into a metal bar spanning the hole. Can I cover over this hole with tile?  Thanks.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wager it's a cleanout.  A place you can run a plumbers snake down the pipe to clear clogs.

Comment: It appears that there's a metal cover over a rubber plug. The 3rd image seems to show that the plug may be deteriorating and falling apart.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to cover it with tile? As far as I know, it hasn't been used in decades.

Comment: You have a cleanout **so you can access the pipe to clear clogs.** Covering it with tile is a very bad idea, even if you haven't had to use it recently. Covering it may also violate plumbing code for your local area.